# how to create the validfrom column

Tags: sql

i have the table as at the bottom

```
Material    createddate    Changedon    Materialresponsible
M1           2015-01-25    2016-01-01        E
M1           2016-01-25    2016-01-20        F
M1           2016-01-25    2016-02-26        G
```

Now i want to create a column 'valid from' base on the createddate and changeon columns, what looks like this

```
Material    createddate    Changedon    validfrom       Materialresponsible
M1           2015-01-25    2016-01-01  2015-01-25           E
M1           2016-01-25    2016-01-20  2016-01-20           F
M1           2016-01-25    2016-02-26   2016-02-26          G
```

Can you please help me to do it?

Thanks

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Material3](
[Material] nvarchar(20) NULL,
createddate date NULL,
[Changedon] date NULL,
[Materialresponsible]  nvarchar(20) NULL,)
INSERT INTO Material3
VALUES ('M1','2015-01-25','2016-01-01','E'),
('M1','2016-01-25','2016-01-20','F'),
('M1','2016-01-25','2016-02-26','G')
```

Comment: How do you determine whaich value to use?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want:

```
select m.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by Material order by ChangedOn) = 1
             then createddate
             else changedon
        end) as validfrom
from dbo.Material3 m;
```